# Cannot create GitHub project board: no "Projects" tab at the top

Tags: github

Step 2 of [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-project-board/#creating-a-repository-project-board) claims that there is a "Projects" tab under each repository's name at the top. I do not see this tab for any of my repositories (example [here](https://github.com/ropensci/drake)).

[image]

### EDIT

Projects are already activated in Settings.

[image]

Comment: I went to the repository in question and the Projects tab was there. Please provide more detail as to your browser, whether or not you are logged in, etc.

Comment: Yes, I am logged in to GitHub, and I am one of the repo admins. I am using 64-bit Firefox 64.0 for Ubuntu.

Comment: I can see it too [https://github.com/ropensci/drake/projects](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/projects)

Comment: Hmm... the direct link works for me even though I cannot see the tab. That is useful.

Comment: Do you have any ad block addon installed and it may eat your tab.

Comment: Wait... I have the Refined Github extension. Disabling it made the Projects tab appear. Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @landau Great news! You should post this as an answer in case someone else encounters the issue :)

Comment: I think @shingo should have first claim to the reputation points. Couldn't have done it without their suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Is the tab enabled?

Maybe the "Projects" tab is disabled in the [**repository settings**](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/settings).

Try to go to `Settings` > `Options` and under `Features`, check `Projects` to enable the tab, as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Repository settings]

---

### 2. Have you checked your add-ons?

It is possible that your browser has an add-on/extension that changes GitHub's interface.

Try to disable Refined GitHub that [removes the tab when there is no project linked to your repository](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/687). Also try to disable your ad-blocker, theme manager (Stylish), etc.

Comment: Would have been nice if that explained it. When I went to Settings, the Projects box was already checked. See the edit to the OP.